# Angular6 ngStyle to apply style dynamically

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular6, styling, ng-style

I am using angular6 and trying to implement background color through inline styling in angular table. If i hard code the values, the background color changes but if i try to put it through variable it remain same.

**Template:**

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="color">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> color </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [ngStyle]="{'background-color':'#element.color'}"> #{{element.color}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use like that for only set one style then try use like that

```
public bgcolor = "red";
```

> note not used (-) here instead of use camelcase style

```
 [style.backgroundColor]="bgcolor"
```

second way used like that for multiple

```
public bgcolor = {
    backgroundColor:"orange"
};

[ngStyle]="bgcolor"
```

for your style used like that

```
[ngStyle]="{ backgroundColor:'#' + element.color }"



<ng-container matColumnDef="color">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> color </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [ngStyle]="{ backgroundColor:'#' + element.color }" > #{{element.color}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: yes but i am using datatable so all the data of table in datasource and every column in table will have different table according to the variable

Comment: <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [ngStyle]="{'background-color':'#element.color'}"> #{{element.color}} </td> so here the row data will come in element and i have to use element.color which has the color data.

Comment: Thanks, yes the dash was a problem as we use that in css Styling.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to assign variable (selectedElementColor) value to the background color, you can do as follows

```
[ngStyle]="{'backgroundColor': selectedElementColor}"
```

If you assign this value based on condition then you can use condition as follows

```
[ngStyle]="value === selectedValue && {'backgroundColor': selectedElementColor}
```

Make sure you are using property backgroundColor and not background-color.

Answer (score 0):

```
<span  [ngStyle]="{'background-color': item.color}"> </span>
```

page service.ts ::

```
  return {
    'toolbarTitle': 'My Pins',
    'items': [
        {
            'id': 1,
            'color' : 'red',
        },
    ]
};
```